# How do you italicize article titles in BibTex using RevTex4.2?

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing, revtex

RevTex 4.2 by default displays journal article titles in the references, but it does not show them in italics. I could go through and italicize each title individually, but is there a way to set them all to be italicized either within the BibTex file or in the main .tex file?

As a minimal working example, I'm working from the overleaf RevTex 4.2 template: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/revtex-4-dot-2-template-and-sample/yydsrzvrqrzs

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se! We discourage Overleaf links as MWEs. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8402/2693 for some discussion. But independent of this, the RevTeX styles match the styles of the journals that require them. I know of no style in which article titles are italicized. They are either in quotation marks or with no special formatting. Italics is used for book and journal titles, and depending on the style a few other non-article titles.

Comment: Hi @AlanMunn, just to address your comment: "no" and "no". Just now a got a request from PRX to change the styles of their own RevTex. They actually want the titles to be in italic, see an e.g.:( https://journals.aps.org/prx/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevX.11.011005) With this being said, I wonder how the author of the post resolved their problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert here, but I was able to fix this by modifying the apsrev4-2.bst file which I got from downloading the revtex4-2-tds.zip file at [https://journals.aps.org/revtex/revtex-faq#download][1]. The actual file was located under revtex-tds\bibtex\bst\revtex\apsrev4-2.bst after downloaded. Once the .bst file is in your overleaf, open it and using ctrl+F, search for {article} including the brackets within the file.

Replace the lines of code below beginning at the "FUNCTION {article}" line up until the "%% Handle special case of SISSA journals which require....." lines so that the file reads:

```
   FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors
  booktitle empty$ {
      "author" output.check
    }{ output } if$
author format.key output
new.block.comma
format.title
    "title" 'bibfield :=
    emphasize
output
new.block.comma
  crossref missing$
%% Handle special case of SISSA journals which require...
```

This at least worked for me, and I hope it can work for others who might need this, too.